# React I have 2 sliders but they are not connected

Tags: reactjs, slider

I have 2 sliders and I want them to connect
When I change one, I want the value of the other to change.

```
const Selector = () => {
    const [firstGas, setFirstGas] = React.useState('');
    const [secondGas, setSecondGas] = React.useState('');
    const marks = [
       ...
    ];
    const marks2 = [
        ...
    ];

    if (marks2.value > 0){
        marks.value = 100-marks2.value;
    }

    const handleChange = (event) => {   
        setFirstGas(event.target.value);
    };
    const handleChange2 = (event) => {
        setSecondGas(event.target.value);
    };
    console.log(firstGas);
    console.log(secondGas);

    return (
    <div>
        <Slider
            aria-label="First Gas"
            defaultValue={80}
            min={80}
            max={100}
            step={null}
            valueLabelDisplay="auto"
            marks={marks}
        />
        <Slider
            aria-label="Second Gas"
            defaultValue={0}
            min={0}
            max={20}
            step={null}
            valueLabelDisplay="auto"
            marks={marks2}
        />
    </div>
    </div>

  );
};

export default Selector;
```

I'm making a website that shows gas mixtures in graph form.
but I couldn't understand this part please help me I'm new to react so I couldn't do it